# Environment with math symboles

Tags: lyx, environments, preamble

I'm trying to make an environment with the code below (at LyX) but it doesn't compile...
I check it the problem is with the `\square` command.
How can I fix it?  (I put this code at the preamble of course)

```
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \textbf{part~.\theexample #1 } \rmfamily}{\medskip \begin{flushleft} $ \square $ \end{flushleft}}
```

It says that the problem is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\endexample ->\medskip $ \square 
                                 $
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solve it!
I just put at the preamble this line:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

LyX loads it **after** I write the  environment...
So when I write it at the beginning it's fix the problem!!

Comment: It’s also defined by some math font packages, and by `unicode-math`.